# Why does setting an element's zindex back to 0 not move it behind other objects in IE9?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-9

This works in IE 6, 7, 8, FF 3.5+, Chrome, Safari but in IE 9 it does not! All I'm doing is moving an object to the front and then moving it back behind the other object again. It moves to the front but does not go back (despite the zIndex being properly set).

All objects are positioned absolute.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>     
</head>
<style>
body
{
    background-color: #c6e2f1;
}

.moveable
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 0;
}

.stationary
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: 1;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div id="moveable" class="moveable"></div>
    <div id="stationary" class="stationary"></div>
    <script>
    var up = false;
    document.getElementById( "stationary" ).onclick = function()
    {
        if ( !up )
        {
            up = true;
            document.getElementById( "moveable" ).style.zIndex = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById( "moveable" ).style.zIndex = 0;
            up = false;
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only way I've been able to get it to work is to increase the zIndex of the other object (the yellow stationary one) EVERY time! If I increase it once, then it'll only work two times and then stop working! What's going on here? (in other words, change object "stationary"'s zIndex to 1, then 2, the 3, etc, while changing "moveable" back to 0)

Comment: Have you tried setting it back to `auto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is happening in IE9, but have you tried just increasing each starting `z-index` by 1, so that rather than change it to 2 then back to 0, you change it to 3 then back to 1.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<style>
body
{
    background-color: #c6e2f1;
}

.moveable
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1;
}

.stationary
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: 2;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div id="moveable" class="moveable"></div>
    <div id="stationary" class="stationary"></div>
    <script>
    var up = false;
    document.getElementById( "stationary" ).onclick = function()
    {
        if ( !up )
        {
            up = true;
            document.getElementById( "moveable" ).style.zIndex = 3;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById( "moveable" ).style.zIndex = 1;
            up = false;
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Weird! So the issue is zindex 0 handling? I'm marking this the answer even though it's not really an answer, but a workaround. (Not your fault, it's Microsoft's fault) BTW, setting it to "-1" also worked.

Comment: I found [this bug report](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html) at quirksmode.org. Apparently it is only when trying to use `z-index: 0` on elements that also have `position`.

Comment: Thanks! Just another reason I hate IE. (Not just because of this bug, but because they'll never fix this bug, at least not in any versions already out)

Answer (score 0):

Style properties ought to be set as strings, not numbers. And IE does have a problem with z-index 0. Use 3 and 2, or 2 and -1, instead.

```
   var up = false;
    document.getElementById( "stationary" ).onclick = function()
    {
        if ( !up )
        {
            up = true;
            document.getElementById( "moveable" ).style.zIndex = '2';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById( "moveable" ).style.zIndex = '-1';
            up = false;
        }
    }
```